# Stopping cascading logical replication

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

Given two primary PG12 servers, A and B, let's setup logical replication from A to B.

`A --> B`

Both servers can and do receive writes, and don't use sequences or unique constraints so there is no conflict.

Is it possible to set up replication from B to A, *without* replicating the data replicated from A?

*Writes from A:*
`A --> B -x-> A`

*Writes from B:*
`B --> A -x-> B`

End result is both databases have the same data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Replication cannot be cyclical.

You seem to be looking for a multi-master solution for PostgreSQL, but there are no open source solutions for that.

If I get that right that you have no unique or primary key constraints on the table, logical replication will not do what you want if the table contains duplicate rows.